# How does the SS and SP registers actually work together?

Tags: linux, pointers, assembly, stack, cpu-registers

I understand that the SS register points to the "start" of the stack and the SP register represents the offset from the SS register to the top of the stack. Am I right? If so, how does it works? knowing that the stack grows from higher addresses to lower. For example:

If I have a stack that goes from the address 0xFF to the address 0x00, my SS register would be pointing to 0xFF, but what does SP contains? An offset so I can do SS - SP = top of the stack? or an actual address?

I believe what is confusing me is that the stack grows to lower addresses. I am using linux/nasm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many detailed explanations for that on the web. Please read: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html

Comment: _"If I have a stack that goes from the address 0xFF to the address 0x00, my SS register would be pointing to 0xFF"_. If `SS` was set to 0xFF your linear address would be `0xFF0 + offset`.

Comment: Note that in linux you can ignore `SS` as if it never existed. It is a protected mode selector to a segment with base address zero (similarly for `CS`, `DS` and `ES`).

Comment: But if i do 0xFF + offset it woluld give me a value larger than the limit doesn't it? for example: SS = 0xFF and SP = 0x1C. Is my top at 0xFF + 0x1C = 0x11B wouldn't that be out of my stack?. About the link provided I've already checked it and it does not answer my question.

Comment: You should read up on the 8086 memory segment architecture. There is a specific relationship between a *segment* register (like `ss` or `ds` or `es`) and an *offset* register (such as `sp` or `bp` or `di` or `si` or `bx`). The real, direct address is `segment << 4 + offset` and enabled the 16-bit 8086 to directly access 1Mbyte (20-bit address) memory. The fact that the stack grows down is completely independent of this. Stacks typically grow down (regardless of OS). That means a `push` decrements the address, then stores the value. A `pop` reads the value, then increments the address.